# Como hago para comparar 2 columnas de diferentes tablas que contienen datos repetidos , para seleccionar los registros que no se repiten

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo un aplicativo que genera requisiciones, y tengo 2 tablas donde guardo los productos y servicios de esta requisición. Se llaman "products_req_view" y "services_req_view", ambas tablas guardan el nit del proveedor que ofrece dicho producto o servicio. Necesito comparar el campo "provider" en ambas tablas y seleccionar solo los nits que no se repiten, para la requisicion #215 por ejemplo.
[image: Tabla donde se guardan los productos de una requisición]

[image: Tabla donde se guardan los servicios de una requisición]

El resultado que yo busco debería verse así, he intentado con DISTINCT, INNER JOIN pero no logro hacerlo
[image: Resultado que se busca]

Necesito hacer esto para capturar los proveedores que corresponden a cada requisición. Tambien pensé en guardar cada consulta en un array y comparar esos 2 arrays con JavaScript o PHP para obtener el resultado que busco, pero aun no se me ocurre como.

Comment: Hola, coloca tus pruebas aqui https://www.db-fiddle.com/ para asi poder ayudarte mejor, saludos

Comment: Intenta `select p.id_requisicion, p.provider from products_req_view p inner join services_req_view s on p.id_requisicion = s.id_requisicion group by p.id_requisicion, p.provider` y comenta que tal te va.

Comment: No me funciono, la que mas cerca he estado es esta: select distinct products_req_view.provider,services_req_view.provider from products_req_view inner join services_req_view on products_req_view.provider != services_req_view.provider and products_req_view.id_requisition = '215'; Pero yo busco el resultado que muestro en la ultima imagen por que la requisición #215 tiene solo 2 proveedores

Comment: Claro pero no tengo tu base de datos para probar, por eso te comente que coloques datos de prueba y generes una url para poder probar y darte la ayuda

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ZvrNxQWUFk7HjipXbytbU/0#&togetherjs=t6D4rOqLMv, perfecto aqui esta

Comment: Hola, prueba esto: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t8cPKhE7KSZsC2i46B26h7/0 y me dices

Comment: Amigo eres un genio aun no entiendo como funciona pero sirve, excelente, aun no tengo ese nivel

Comment: Tranquilo estamos para ayudar, en la respuesta te coloque una pequeña descripción

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo hablado y de acuerdo al los datos que colocaste:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
products_req_view.provider
FROM products_req_view 
LEFT JOIN services_req_view on products_req_view.provider != services_req_view.provider 
AND products_req_view.id_requisition = '215' AND services_req_view.provider is null;
```

> LEFT JOIN seleciona asi esten vacios, y con la validación del "is null" validas los únicos que no esten vacios

Así debe traerte todos los únicos de ambas tablas y te dará el resultado que deseas en al imagen de prueba.